# Heroku/Go trouble with CORS, remote request

Tags: go

I have a backend in Go on Heroku, and my frontend is being served by another Go app on Heroku. I am trying to make requests to the backend from the frontend and I am getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://grafulator.herokuapp.com/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.
```

I understand the error, and that it is something I need to set in the backends header for each route. I have tried doing this and it does not solve the problem.

The requests work in Postman to the backend, but the problem comes when I try to make these requests from a web browser, either locally or my frontend served on heroku.

Things I have tried:

```
router.GlobalOPTIONS = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method") != "" {
        // Set CORS headers
        header := w.Header()
        header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", header.Get("Allow"))
        header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    }

    // Adjust status code to 204
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
})
```

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

```
func main() {
    // BasicAuth username and password
    user := ""
    pass := ""

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "9000" // Default port if not specified
    }

    DefaultUser()

    // HTTPRouter Settings and Routes
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.POST("/login/", BasicAuth(RouteLogin, user, pass))
    router.POST("/upload/", JWTAuth(RouteUpload))

    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS"},
    })
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, c.Handler(router)))
}
```

```
handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(router)
fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", handler))
```

Comment: I resolved this by serving the frontend with the backend Go app. But I'd still like help getting remote requests to work in my Go app if anyone knows anything, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS only happens on the browser. Browser sends a preflight request whose method is OPTION to check if it is allowed to send the original requests.

If you use the following code, it works. You do not need any extra CORS setting. Just remove the other codes regarding CORS.

Backend:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "9000" // Default port if not specified
    }

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/upload", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
        writer.Write([]byte("test body"))
    })

    handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(router)
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, handler))
}
```

Frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script>
        fetch("http://localhost:9000/upload")
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Response:
[Succes Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJHyQ.png)

If you replace last two lines in main.go with the following line, you will get CORS error again.

```
fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
```

Comment: That's weird, this is how I had my original code, exactly this. It was not working for cross site requests. I am thinking there is a problem with my Heroku app, I switched the frontend to being served by the same Go app as the backend and CORS is now working since it isn't a remote request. However, my app is randomly not working. When I visit the URL it will say "There's nothing here, yet" and I have to refresh the page a few times to actually get my app to load.